# Upgrading postgresql from version 11 to 12 results in "Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing"

Tags: postgresql, macos

I ran

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

and after a long series of updates the final results are:

```
==> Migrating and upgrading data...
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                 ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Checking for tables WITH OIDS                               ok
Checking for invalid "sql_identifier" user columns          ok
Creating dump of global objects                             ok
Creating dump of database schemas
                                                            ok
Checking for presence of required libraries                 fatal

Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing from the
new installation.  You can add these libraries to the new installation,
or remove the functions using them from the old installation.  A list of
problem libraries is in the file:
    loadable_libraries.txt

Failure, exiting
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 11 to 12 failed!
==> Removing empty postgresql initdb database...
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.9/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 16` exited with 1.
```

The only notes about this I could find were about `pg` developers mulling whether to print out the offending databases involved: it was  unclear what the fix would be.  Any hints ?

**Update**  There is *no* loadable_libraries.txt in the directory that this was run.

Comment: Read the error message. What is in `loadable_libraries.txt`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Fair point: I neglected to mention in the question: `There is *no* loadable_libraries.txt in the directory that this was run.:`. Updated now

Comment: Perhaps it is in some other directory?

Comment: Yes you're right - it's in `/usr/local/var/log/loadable_libraries.txt`  . The error message should have mentioned that -and well I should have also done a `find . -name loadable_libraries.txt` .  Feel free to make an answer

Comment: Sigh. Great, you found it. Now how about reading it?

Comment: I did and it solves the problem - do you want to create an answer? You may have misunderstood - I am not asking for more info but rather if you want to get credit for the result.  If not then I will make an answer out of your comment. Your call.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think this is too trivial for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am creating an answer based on the comment from @LaurenzAlbe.  The `loadable_libraries.txt` **was not placed in the current directory from which the command**

was run .  Instead let's go find where it went:

```
$find / -name loadable_libraries.txt
/usr/local/var/log/loadable_libraries.txt
```

So what's in that file?

```
06:22:24/cidervuong2 $cat /usr/local/var/log/loadable_libraries.txt
could not load library "$libdir/pg_background": ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_background": No such file or directory
Database: bluej
```

I looked into that error:

ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_background"

and there is no useful information.  I went ahead and nuked `postgresql` again and this time it installed cleanly.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies postgres
brew install postgres
brew services start postgresql  # actually already started
```

and `pg` came up cleanly this time

```
  502 84118     1   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.03 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
  502 84120 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer
  502 84121 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.03 postgres: background writer
  502 84122 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.01 postgres: walwriter
  502 84123 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.01 postgres: autovacuum launcher
  502 84124 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.01 postgres: stats collector
  502 84125 84118   0  6:33AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: logical replication launcher
```